# Flutter/How to fill space with Vertical Wrap?

Tags: flutter

I am using Vertical Wrap and would like to fill the space. Is there an alternative package or something with a widget that specifies the number of pieces to be arranged vertically and then horizontally?

[this is image]
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SqIN.png

Comment: You might want to take a look at this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view.

Answer (score 0):

you can use expanded widget to fill space. when use 2 expanded widget in one row, size of 2 widget will be equal.

```
Column(
  children: [
    Row(
      children: [
        Widget1(),
        Widget3(),
        Expanded(child: Container(),), // you need this
        WidgetLongData()
      ],
    ),
    Row(
      children: [
        Widget2(),
        Expanded(child: WidgetLongData()),
        Expanded(child: WidgetLongData()),
      ],
    )
  ],
)
```

Comment: This sollution would certainly not work as Wrap which OP requested. For quite a lot of data e.g. list mapped for render with 100+ values, this will be insane to implement.